# redirect to previous page after successful admin login

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have `authorized.html` page which needs a admin login to view so when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/authorized/` it takes me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/%3Fnext%3D/authorized/`, which is expected. I used the below code in `view.py` file to built this functionality:

```
class authorizedView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/authorized.html'
    login_url = '/admin/'
```

But after the successful admin login it didn't take me back to `authorized.html` instead it directs to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/?next=/authorized/` which is just `admin page` and not the page that I want `authorized.html`. `authorized.html` is in `home/templates/home/` where `home` is the django app that i created. How to do this? Please provide the detailed steps, i'am new to django!

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py`, make sure you specify where to navigate to after successful login, for example:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/authorized/'
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url for more details.

Also, you could decorate your view with `@login_required` and let Django handle the login portion of things and redirect you back there too. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator for details of this.

Comment: In the official documentation `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is defined as `The URL or named URL pattern where requests are redirected after login when the LoginView doesn’t get a next GET parameter.` but in my case `next` parameter gets the correct value i.e. `authorized.html`

Comment: and why should i add this to `settings.py`, i can have multiple `authorized.html` like `authorized1.html`, `authorized2.html` etc.; editing `settings.py` file this way will redirect all urls after admin-login to same page which is `authorized.html`